# EACCES: permission denied installing NWjs on Mac using npm

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, nwjs

I'm getting the following errors as I try to install NWjs on Mac using npm. I'm new to NWjs, anyhelp will be appreciated. Thanks

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nw/nwjs'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nw@0.44.2 postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nw@0.44.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/onaapo/.npm/_logs/2020-02-21T05_26_02_243Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
sudo npm install -g [ENTER YOUR PACKAGE NAME NW OR NWJS] --unsafe-perm
```

**Note:** Be aware that you are doing this as elevated user, so please only do it if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Suggestions to use sudo with npm should disclose the risks of doing so.